# Prestashop custom php file with query

Tags: php, include, connection, prestashop, require

I am new to prestashop and I have made a custom php file which is called by ajax and has SQL queries. The problem is that this file doesn't have a connection. What should I include or require in it to achieve it?

Comment: Please read this link:-  https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/269288-get-data-from-a-custom-table-into-a-custom-page/

Answer (score 4):

If your absolutely **must**, include these files (corret the path based on your file location):

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../init.php');

Db::getInstance()->exec($sql);
```

These files will load all the configs and autoload PrestaShop classes (but will start no process). You may write your code below.

However, this is no recommended either. Ajax calls from FO should go to a `FrontController` (Default or a module-made FrontContoller). Same goes for Ajax calls to AdminControllers.

You may also respond to Ajax calls from within your module upon init.

All Ajax calls should send token with them to prevent CSRF and other security breaches.